# Please help me out for the following scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I am having a database of a call center.
My requirement is to select only the people who have called (92222, 122323, 9988898).

Please could you help me to write a query for this.

Comment: select * from table where column_name in (92222, 122323, 9988898)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select all_people from call_centerDB where called_nos=92222 OR called_nos=122323 OR called_nos=9988898
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really much info to go on since you haven't given us any schema details but it's likely to be something like:

```
select      p.person
from        people p,
            calls c
where       p.person_id = c.person_id
and         c.call_target in ('92222', '122323', '9988898')
```

This would be for the following minimal schema:

```
people:
    person_id primary key
    person
calls:
    person_id references people(person_id)
    call_target
```

Depending on how complicated your schema is, the query you need may be completely different but this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
select * from tbl_call_center where called_no IN (92222, 122323, 9988898)
```